# How to conditionally include/exclude a field from a query in Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

I have the following mongoose schema:

```
export class Auction {
    ... Some other fields ...    

    @Prop({ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: User.name, required: true, index: true })
    seller!: string | User | Types.ObjectId

    @Prop({
        type: [{
            bidderId: { type: Types.ObjectId, required: true, select: false },
            amount: { type: Number, required: true },
            date: { type: Date, required: true }
        }],
        select: false
    })
    bids?: Bid[]
}
```

I need an endpoint method that returns the `bids` of an `Auction`, but with the following rule:

include `bids.bidderId` if the user who's requesting the bids is the seller of the auction, else exclude `bids.bidderId` from the projection.

How can I implement that? assuming I have this method:

```
async getBidsOfAuction(auctionId: string, user: UserDocument) {
  // In case user.id === auction.seller, return all the fields including bids.bidderId
    return await this.auctionModel.findOne({_id: auctionId, seller: user.id}).select('+bids +bids.bidderId') 
 // else, exclude bids.bidderId
    return await this.auctionModel.findById(auctionId).select('+bids')
}
```

I just can't know if `auction.seller === user.id` before I query the auction, and I don't want to manually (in JS) remove `bids.bidderId` from the bids array after the query because its seems redundant.

Is there a way to conditionally query **If the auction's seller equals to the user id, include `bids.bidderId`, else exclude**?

Comment: Retrieve the `bids.bidderId` anyway and if it's not the seller delete it before sending to the client.

Comment: This won't scale well, Imagine I have an array of 1000 bids (which is easily possible in this app), that means I have to mutate an array of 1000 (for each request). If there is a way to do this in the DB its much better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
async getBidsOfAuction(auctionId: string, user: UserDocument) {
    user.aggregate().match({_id: auctionId})
   .project({
  'seller': 1,
  'type': 1,
  'bids': {
    $cond: {
      if: {
        '$eq': ['$seller', user.id]
      },
      then: '$bids.bidderId',
      else: null
    }
  },
})
.exec(callback);   

}
```

Comment: I need to know if ```user.id  === auction.seller``` for me to include ```bids.bidderId```, but i can't check that condition before the entire auction document is queried, which i dont want

Comment: This works, returns an array ```bids``` that includes all the bidderIds, but I also need to include ```bids.amount``` and ```bids.date```, is it possible?

Comment: $cond: {
      if: {
        '$eq': ['$seller', user.id]
      },
      then: '$bids',
      else: null
    }

Comment: In the ```else```, is there a way to return ```$bids.date``` and ```$bids.amount```  instead of ```null```?

Comment: can u try like this 
      else: {"date":$bids.date,"amount": $bids.amount}